# I am unable to visualize anything on tensorboard. How to fix this?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorboard

I am currently using Tensorflow on Linux, and when I launch tensorboard and go to the localhost using Firefox, I am only able to see what's enclosed in the image. I am unable to interact with anything, and the whole thing is unresponsive. How do you think I might be able to fix this?

[Tensorboard Window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XJFl8.png)

Comment: Did you try other browsers? Which version of Firefox is that?

Comment: Please can you provide what versions of Tensorboard, Firefox, Linux. Have you checked Tensorboard GH issues to see if there is anyone else having the same problem?

Comment: I am currently using Firebox 17.0.3, tensorboard 2.3.0, and Redhat 7.6. Could the issue be with any of these versions? I checked Tensorboard GH but couldn't find anyone facing this issue.